# Unable to delete a developer's certificate

Tags: iphone

I mistakenly imported someone else's certificate(with his priv key) to my mac, and now I have two developer's certificates shown in my xCode. When I delete the unneeded certificate with its key in "Keychain Access", both the cert and the priv key magically reappear after sometime, how can I get rid of this? Is it automatically imported from somewhere e.g. the iphone developer's site?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried deleting from `iPhone Configuration Utility` app? It never comes back when I delete it from there.

EDIT: You can only delete provisioning profiles from iphone configuration utility app. To delete certificates/keys, you have to use `keychain access`.

Note that when you add a provisioning profile, all the associated certificates are added to your keychain as well. So deleting a certi won't help you, and it will always come back as in your case. All of them.

[Here](http://www.saileshmittal.in/2011/04/understading-ios-code-signing.html) is a blog post that I had written for some code-signing insight. Here is a quote from this post:

> Now, when you download a profile to your machine, all the associated certificates also get added to your keychain. You can check that under "Certificates" category in the keychain app. But unless there is at least one certificate with the corresponding private key in your keychain, you wont be able to sign the app.

Point is, it is the private key that xcode looks for for the certificates that you already have. Since you have a private key, xcode lists that as a available option for signing. So, its the `private key` that you want to delete and not the certi. So go to `Keys` section in the `keychain access`, find the culprit key, and shoot it.

Comment: How can I delete CERTS in this app? It seems I can only delete PROVISIONING PROFILES...

Comment: Thanks! I kept deleting just the certificate from the keychain, and magically, Xcode kept putting it back! Upon deleting **both** the old **private key** and the **certificate**, I was finally able to build.

Answer (score 0):

XCode automatically does this if you log in on xCode with your developer's username and password.
It will generate a team provisioning profile and automatically download and install it.
To change it, go to the apple provisioning portal (http://developer.apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the "Keychain Access" app which can be found in the Utilities folder. In the "My Certificates" category, you will find all stored certificates on your machine and can easily right click and delete the certificate & private key.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the cert in  "Keychain Access" app, the problem is the cert I deleted automatically reappears after some time...

Comment: In Xcode 4, go to Window -> Organizer and remove all the provisioning profiles in the section titled "Library." Also you may consider disabling 'automatic device provisioning' to ensure that you are in full control of your development profiles etc.